# br or newline in XUL

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

How to move text to a new line in XUL without `html:br`? is there a newline character in XUL or something like this?

```
<description>
    Some
    text
    here
</description>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<description>` element can respect line breaks, the same as `<html:p>`. You simply have to use the [`white-space` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop):

```xml
<description style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
    Some
    text
    here
</description>
```