# Newline characters in XUL listbox listitems

Tags: listbox, newline, xul, listitem

I have tried several CSS tricks to get a XUL listbox to display items with newline characters interpreted. This would be useful, as I am using the listitem-iconic class to add an icon which increases the listitem height significantly.

A [previous question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031215/br-or-newline-in-xul) alluded to using the white-space CSS attribute for  tags in XUL, however the below code did not have any effect. Currently, any lines split with newline characters run together.

```
listitem {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style applies to the wrong element. If you look at the [`listbox.xml` binding](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/listbox.xml) or inspect your list with [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/), you will see that `listitem-iconic` gets a bunch of "anonymous" children. The final structure looks like this:

```xml
<listitem class="listitem-iconic">
  <listcell class="listcell-iconic">
    <image class="listcell-icon"/>
    <label class="listcell-label" flex="1" crop="right"/>
  </listcell>
</listitem>
```

The text goes into the `label` element, so that's the one that you should apply your style to. So this CSS code should work:

```css
listitem .listcell-label {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer; I'm still having no luck with this problem though. I see the CSS style applied in DOM Inspector and have tried several newline representations with no change. I may switch to a `<richlistbox>` element to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The white-space attribute is only active for the `<description>` tag, so you should wrap your item inside `<description>` and then in `<listitem>`.